# Groupby dataframe and get count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like

```
name counts
one [2,5]
two [3,4]
one [5,9]
```

I wanna group it and get the count and all list values together like

```
one 2 [2, 5, 5, 9]
two 1 [3,4]
```

I am familiar with group by in python dataframe but am not sure how to get count and combine all values into list.

Answer (score 0):

Try look at `groupby` with `sum`

```
df.groupby('name',sort=False)['counts'].agg(['count','sum'])
```

Comment: Always good to remember OP that `sum` is really nice syntactically but gets really slow with many entries. `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is a better option in those cases ;p

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = pd.DataFrame({'name':['one', 'two', 'one'], 'counts':[[2,5], [3,4], [5,9]]})



x.groupby('name').agg(['size', np.sum])
```

yields

```
     counts              
       size           sum
name                     
one       2  [2, 5, 5, 9]
two       1        [3, 4]
```

You group by name, then look at the size of  the groups and the sum of the lists!